# Data table sorting by date

Tags: jquery, sorting, date

I'm using jQuery data table and I got stuck at date sorting in data table.

My date format is like `02/12/2014`, it seems, that sorting is being done considering it as a

string doing sorting like `28/11/2014`, `26/11/2014`, `05/12/2014`.

Comment: You may try creating custom sorting for the datatable: https://datatables.net/development/sorting

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
      "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
          if (a == null || a == "") {
            return 0;
          }
          var ukDatea = a.split('/');
         return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
     },

     "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
     },

     "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
         return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
     }
   } );
```